# Selenium unable to locate element python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-code

Why do I get this error?
Can't click on button error unable to find element.
I tried to put (time.sleep) but it doesn't work.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxQ03.png)

Comment: Try not to use so many actions. Just WebElement.click(). Also try to download CSS Helper, or Chro Path charome extensions it will make your life better.Do not use absolute xpath for POM.

Comment: Problem is in chrome or site.I need to make xpath (not copying with chrome) and use execute_script to scroll.@GajJulije